# What is the difference between "perpetrator" and "transgressor"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I don't quite understand when one might be applied, but not the other.

Also, is anyone who committed a transgression a transgressor, or might they also be perpetrators? Does it make a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look in any dictionaries? What did you find?

Comment: Unfortunately, that both words serve as synonyms for each other and have very close meanings... But the answers below are very helpful in understanding the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the definitions:

> **Perpetrate**
> Carry out or commit (a harmful, illegal, or immoral action)
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/perpetrate)
>
> **Transgress**
> 1 Go beyond the limits of (what is morally, socially, or legally acceptable)
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transgress)

*Perpetrate* refers primarily to the action while *transgress* refers primarily to the state of unlawfulness. The difference is similar to that between having pain *inflicted* and simply *feeling* pain.

As such, if we accept the primary idea of *wrongdoing* (however defined, be it legally, socially, or morally, etc), then very loosely and informally (and mainly visually), a *perpetrator* is someone who has **done** something wrong while a *transgressor* is someone who has done something **wrong**. The words have almost identical meaning - one is more concerned about the action and the other about the guilt.

Answer (score 1):

Transgress is milder. Perpetrate is much stronger. Transgressors break a rule, perpetrators break the law.

A transgression might be is someone shows up at your formal dinner in jeans and a T-shirt instead of a tuxedo. If you then stab that person for it, you have perpetrated a crime. They broke a social rule, you broke the law.

Answer (score 0):

*Perpetrator* and *transgressor* are both agent nominalizations -- 'one who `VP`s' -- of transitive verbs. They're both from Latin (polysyllabic, and -*or* instead or -*er* agentive suffix), and therefore falute highly, which means they're used in legal, political, and other dramatic contexts.

The transitive verbs they're formed from (*perpetrate, transgress*) have different objects.

- *perpetrate* takes an **event** noun phrase as an object
  *They perpetrated the heist with their gats.*  (note falution mismatch)
- *transgress* takes an object noun phrase referring to a rule, law, or boundary
  *They have transgressed the universal principle of apostrophe placement.*

This is pretty common; often near-synonyms turn out to have different affordances,
if you look carefully, like the difference between

***steal***, which takes a noun phrase denoting the loot from a theft as its object,
and
   ***rob***, which takes an object noun phrase denoting the victim of the theft.

- *They stole $28,000 (from the store).*
- *The robbed the store (of $28,000).*